# pseudo element does not work properly on Firefox and IE

Tags: css, pseudo-element

As I know, new technologies are supported very well on both latest Firefox and IE. But in this situation, I dont understand why these pseudo elements cannot show properly on both browsers. Of course, everything is ok on Chrome. Thank you very much for your help!

Live demo:
http://codepen.io/victorcruzte/pen/grWjmy

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn-disconnect" cmd-disconnect="facebook">Disconnect</button>
```

CSS

```
.btn-disconnect {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 7.69231em;
    color: white;
    font-size: .92857em;
    background-color: #6b6c72;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.btn-disconnect:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.14286em;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: .42857em;
}

.btn-disconnect:after {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

These are screenshots:
[image]

As you can see, in the chrome version, the minus sign stands beside the text. But in firefox version, the minus is pushed to the top of the button.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, latest Chrome and Firefox look identical.

Comment: My firefox version is 45.0.1, which is the latest, and it does not look the same =.=

Comment: Maybe add a screenshot and what OS you are using?

Comment: ok please wait for a minute

Comment: My OS is Windows 7 Build 7601

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Firefox 45.0.1 on OS X. Maybe try resetting some more of the default button styles, which are somewhat OS dependent.